# Holding the windows to display an HSI using spectral in Python

Tags: python-3.x, spectral-python

I am using spectral to view an hyperspectral image for a specific band in python. This is my code.

```
from spectral import *

img=open_image('flc1.lan')
view = imshow(img)
print(view)
gt=open_image('flc1.lan').read_band(0)
view1= imshow(classes=gt)
print(view1)
```

The image does pop up, but then closes. Is there any kind of function like waitkey to hold the window?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use :

```
envi.save_image(give_file_name, image_name, ext='hdr')
```

to save the image locally and view it later, at your discretion

Comment: It is usually because of some package dependency issue.
check with matplotlib-base or wxPython